# How do I apply Full Join in my SQL and gives NULL if no common?

Tags: mysql

There are Two Tables with client data:

```
ReportID   Name  CountRead ReadTime
100        A     1         10:00
200        B     2         02:00

ReportID   Name  CountOpen OpenTime
100        A     1         09:00
200        A     1         11:00
300        C     1         13:00
```

I would like to combines the two tables with report ID and clientName as identifier, 
if both Read and Open have values for same clientName for the same report then combine them into one row, 
and gives null values if there are no values on either Open or Read:

```
ReportID   Name  CountOpen OpenTime  CountRead Time
100        A     1         09:00     1         10:00
200        A     1         11:00     Null      Null
200        B     Null      Null      2         02:00
300        C     1         13:00     Null      NULL
```

Comment: can you explain to me why these are two tables to begin with? what makes the data so different that you have to have it separated?

Comment: these are the two different sources table and I need to combine them...